# Pandas sample() with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe (shortened) :

```
+-------+------------+--------+----------+-------+------+
| index | id_product | margin | supplier | price | seen |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+-------+------+
| 0     | 100000000  | 92.00  | 14       | 0.56  | 2    |
| 1     | 100000230  | 72.21  | 27       | 8.17  | 0    |
| 2     | 100001440  | 72.07  | 15       | 16.20 | 687  |
| 3     | 100002331  | 30.55  | 13       | 41.67 | 0    |
| 7     | 100001604  | 35.17  | 27       | 18.80 | 491  |
| ...   | ...        | ...    | ...      | ...   | ...  |
| 9830  | 100000320  | 77.78  | 18       | 13.33 | 0    |
| 9831  | 100000321  | 77.78  | 98       | 13.33 | 0    |
| 9832  | 100000443  | 77.78  | 17       | 13.33 | 4587 |
| 9834  | 100000292  | 88.13  | 3        | 10.56 | 0    |
| 9835  | 100000236  | 72.21  | 18       | 10.56 | 0    |
+-------+------------+--------+----------+-------+------+
```

What I am trying to do is to extract randomly 3 rows, using `df.sample(3)` maybe, but with this conditions :

- the 3 rows selected should have 3 **ecom_id** different :  (14,27,13) is good, (14,27,14) is not.
- rows with higher **margins** should be privileged. I use `weights='margin'`, it works fine.
- rows with lower **seen** should be privileged. Is it possible to reverse the weight count with sample() to privilege lowest values ?
- The 3 selected rows should be found in 3 different price slicing : first selected row should have a price < 20.0, second one should have a price between 30 and 50, and finally the third and last selected row should have a price > 80.

Is this possible ?

I have tried stuff like :

```
pr_1_pd = pr_pd.loc[pr_pd['price'] < 20]
pr_2_pd = pr_pd.loc[(pr_pd['price'] > 30) & (pr_pd['price'] < 50)]
pr_3_pd = pr_pd.loc[pr_pd['price'] > 80]

pr_1_pd = pr_1_pd.sort_values(by=['margin','seen'],ascending=[False,True])
pr_2_pd = pr_2_pd.sort_values(by=['margin','seen'],ascending=[False,True])
pr_3_pd = pr_3_pd.sort_values(by=['margin','seen'],ascending=[False,True])
```

But I'm not sure how to combine all the filters together

Comment: A lot of things going on here. Here are the tips: 1. sample without replacement 2. invert  `seen`, e.g. 1/(1+x), 3. Stratified sampling can be achieved by combining groupby and sample 4. need to create discontinous price groups (0-20, 30-50, 80-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - the 3 rows selected should have 3 ecom_id different : (14,27,13) is good, (14,27,14) is not.

Setting `replace=False` in `pd.sample` should achieve this if `ecom_id` is unique.

> - rows with lower seen should be privileged. Is it possible to reverse the weight count with sample() to privilege lowest values ?

You could invert the weights `new_weight = 1 / seen` to achieve this.

> - The 3 selected rows should be found in 3 different price slicing : first selected row should have a price < 20.0, second one should have a price between 30 and 50, and finally the third and last selected row should have a price > 80.

You'll have to sample from `pr_1_pd`, `pr_2_pd`, and `pr_3_pd` individually and then combine the results using `pd.concat` to achieve this.

Comment: How do I add "new_weight" ?